# printing selected values from a list on one line

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing, line

I am trying to print selected values from a list on one line in python 3.

Here is the code:

```
names = ['dog', 'house', 'in', 'is', 'the']
print (names [0])
```

prints result = `dog`

What I want to be able to do is to add list value index 2 so that the result would be = `dog in`.
And that it prints on one line.
I tried searching online and here but could not find a solution.

Comment: `print(names[0], names[2])`.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard thanks that totally solved it, i guess i am a true beginner but i could not find the answer anywhere, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you currently have is this:

```
names = ['dog', 'house', 'in', 'is', 'the']
print (names [0])
```

I believe what you are asking is that it will will print "dog in":

```
names = ['dog', 'house', 'in', 'is', 'the']
print (names [0], names[2])
```

Doing so will print both dog and in.